# How to set affinity on multiple cpu cores of a single CPU not on Multiple CPUs?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, multicore

I am currently working in C multi-threading on server having multiple hexa-core cpus. I want to set affinity of some of my threads to respective cores of a single CPU. I have used pthread_setaffinity_np() and also  sched_setaffinity() but i guess the set affinity on the cpus not the cores. am I right?

Comment: By your mention of `sched_setaffinity` I'm guessing you're using Linux, so I've updated the tags to reflect that.

Comment: I'd think the default APIs do not differentiate physical CPUs, they only see the cores, possibly even Hyper-threading "fake cores". But this should be easy enough to determine, by looking at cpu count reported by API, and compare that to real CPU/core/Hyper-threading count.

Comment: The CPUs that both `sched_setaffinity` and `pthread_setaffinity_np` are referring to are logical cores.

Comment: /cpu/proc shows i have 12 hexacore CPUs.But while setting affinity of two threads on SET 0 and SET 1 respectively. I could find them running on different physical CPUs rather than 2 cores of 1 CPU.

Comment: You probably mean `/proc/cpuinfo`  (there is no `/cpu/` directory on most Linuxes)

Comment: yes the sorry.. /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: Hey Sorry I was wrong lscpu gave me correct info..actually i have a single cpu having 6 cores with hyperthreading... :-) so it actually binds with logical CPU thanks alot.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pthread_setaffinity_np()` et al operate in terms of logical CPUs (i.e. cores), not physical ones (i.e. CPU sockets).

Comment: /cpu/proc shows i have 12 hexacore CPUs.But while setting affinity of two threads on SET 0 and SET 1 respectively. I could find them running on different physical CPUs rather than 2 cores of 1 CPU.

Comment: Hey Sorry I was wrong lscpu gave me correct info..actually i have a single cpu having 6 cores with hyperthreading... :-) so it actually binds with logical CPU thanks alot.. :-)